# Giving IIS database access [denied]

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am compiling my asp.net app and it works fine with the compiler. I am able to insert data into the sql server db. I am using win authentication

When I try the same thing from IIS server(asp.net 4.0...) I am able to run the app; however, I am unable to add data into the database

This is the error that I get:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5050218
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2275
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +35
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +183
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +239
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +524
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +479
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand command, DataSourceOperation operation) +394
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteInsert(IDictionary values) +407
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Insert(IDictionary values, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +89
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.HandleInsert(String commandArg, Boolean causesValidation) +377
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +612
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +112
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +125
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +169
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +9
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +176
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

What am i doing wrong?

The event logger is showing this:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 8/22/2011 12:27:38 PM 
Event time (UTC): 8/22/2011 7:27:38 PM 
Event ID: 0f3bf171f8a94c06940e519fde613209 
Event sequence: 19 
Event occurrence: 4 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-2-129585142179013397 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ 
    Machine name: DEV-104 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 1280 
    Process name: aspnet_wp.exe 
    Account name: DEV-104\ASPNET 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: SqlException 
    Exception message: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand command, DataSourceOperation operation)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteInsert(IDictionary values)
   at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Insert(IDictionary values, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.HandleInsert(String commandArg, Boolean causesValidation)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost/Default.aspx 
    Request path: /Default.aspx 
    User host address: 127.0.0.1 
    User: MLABS\Agordon 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: DEV-104\ASPNET 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 1 
    Thread account name: DEV-104\ASPNET 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand command, DataSourceOperation operation)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteInsert(IDictionary values)
   at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Insert(IDictionary values, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.HandleInsert(String commandArg, Boolean causesValidation)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


Custom event details: 

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

please note that i am using IIS 5.1

Comment: Try logging into the database directly from Enterprise Manager using the credentials from your web-config...if it doesn't work it's an authentication issue.

Comment: @prisoner connecting to sql server works fine with VS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to change your application user, Open your IIS, select your application in left tree, go to action panel and click on basic settings in the opened window click on connect as button select IIS User, or create a user with full access, then select it.

maybe the following links for IIS 5.0, 5.1 and 6.0 will help.

[permissions and user rights for an IIS 5.0, IIS 5.1, or IIS 6.0 Web server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271071)

[How to configure Web server permissions for Web content in IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313075)

[Default permissions and user rights for IIS 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812614)

[Database is read-only or asp.net account has not write permission](http://leksodav.wordpress.com/2009/05/10/169/)

hope this help.

Comment: im sorry i do not see basic settings

Comment: which version of iis you're using ?

Comment: The way I said is for IIS 7 I'm not familiar with IIS 5.1, so let me search for you.

Comment: I edited post and I added some links, maybe those links are your answer.

Comment: thank you for the update but those links do not help with sql server connection

Comment: I will inform you If I found something.

Comment: It has been a while since I researched it I think setting the app pool identity requires IIS 6 or later (win server 2003).  Setting up a designated account and using impersonation may be your best option.

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting the situation correctly you are not authenticating to the SQL server.

When you are running the app from within Visual Studio it runs under your own credentials.  When it is deployed to the server then it runs under the credential of the application pool.  Windows authentication in IIS means that the application code is able to see your windows login information to tell who you are, however it is not able to relay that information to any other systems.  In SQL server it means it is expecting to receive a user token that it can authenticate against the domain.

So when running locally the app sees that you as the user are yourself, and then issues commands to SQL as you, because it is executing under your security context.  When running in IIS however it still sees that you are the user, but it submits the commands to SQL under the security context of the application pool it runs in.  By default this is generally a service account on the local machine, which does not authenticate across the domain.

There are several possible ways to fix it, my preferred method is to change the security context of the app pool to a domain account which has the appropriate permissions in SQL.  Some other options are to include the credentials for a SQL login in your connection string and enable impersonation.  There are likely a few other ways to fix it as well but they are not coming to mind readily

Comment: thanks so much! how do i  change the security context of the app pool to a domain account which has the appropriate permissions in SQL.

Comment: Look in the advanced settings on the right in IIS when viewing an application pool.  Under that tab, the user that the pool runs under is listed.  Add or change that user to an account in SQL server that should have limited access to your database.

Comment: @josh sorry how do i get to advanced settings?

Comment: @rozewell can you tell me how to do this